# Using mask to pick between vectorised equations numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, mask

I have a Problem with a mask operation. I use the Finite Difference Methode on a grid (Matrix) with boundary conditions. To calculate the Boundary Conditions I Use the Energy Balance.
So I have 5 vectorised Equations (Eq0 - Eq4), BC declares which Equation to use for the index. To pick the Eq I use a mask:

```
mask = [0,1,2,3,4]
I = np.identity(5)
e0, e1, e2, e3, e4 = I[:,0], I[:,1], I[:,2], I[:,3], I[:,4]
```

BC is my matrix with the cases, which Equation to use on that index. Like:

```
BC =
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. ... 2. 2. 0.]
 [0. 0. 4. ... 4. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 4. ... 4. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 3. ... 3. 3. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]

for n in range(1,Nt):
    Mn = np.copy(M)
    M[1:Nx,1:Ny] = (mask==BC[1:Nx,1:Ny]).dot(e0) * Eq0 + (mask==BC[1:Nx,1:Ny]).dot(e1) * Eq1 + (mask==BC[1:Nx,1:Ny]).dot(e2) * Eq2 + (mask==BC[1:Nx,1:Ny]).dot(e3) * Eq3 + (mask==BC[1:Nx,1:Ny]).dot(e4) * Eq4
```

I tried different ways to mask the Equations out, but always got an error.

```
np.dot(mask==BC[1:Nx,1:Ny],e0)  --> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (18,) (51,51) 

(1*(mask==BC[1:Nx,1:Ny])).dot(e0) --> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'dot'

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'dot'
```

I hope you got my Problem and can help out.
Thankyou

Comment: Hi, I changed from the mask version to use numpy.where(). (mask==BC[1:Nx,1:Ny]).dot(e0) -- > np.where(BC[1:Nx,1:Ny]==0,1,0), now I dont get an error. But the calculations are wrong, but I think that is a problem of my equations.

Comment: I find your overall problem hard to follow, but maybe this will help?  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html  - it's like np.where() but for multiple conditions at once.

Comment: HI Thankyou. When you look at the BC matrix you can see for every node one number. I vecorised the Equations and every number has the corresponding equation. Like when  BC[1:Nx,1:Ny] = 4 , calculate with Equation 4, the other become 0.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you want is:

```
Eq = np.diag([Eq0, Eq1, Eq2, Eq3, Eq4])
```

and then your final line would be

```
M[1:Nx,1:Ny] = (mask[None, None, :] == BC[1:Nx, 1:Ny]).dot(Eq).sum(-1)
```

But without runnable code it's difficult to be sure.

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your response. When I look at your example I do not get the part 'mask[None,None, :]' what does that mean?

Comment: when I try your solution I get an error in line one : Eq = np.diag([Eq0, Eq1, Eq2, Eq3, Eq4]) --> ValueError: Input must be 1- or 2-d.

Comment: I'm not going to guess what your input shapes are beyond what I already have.  Try writing another question with runnable code and full error trace so folks can understand what you want.

Comment: You are right, the code is quite messed up so I didnt wanted to upload it.

Answer (score 0):

my Code is working now. I didn't get the mask to work. The Answer from @Daniel F. may working, but I didn't manage to make it work.

I ended up using  [numpy.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) like this for my vectorized Equations:

```
M[1:Nx,1:Ny] = np.where(BC[1:Nx,1:Ny]==0,1,0)*Eq0 \
 + np.where(BC[1:Nx,1:Ny]==1,1,0)*Eq1 \
 + np.where(BC[1:Nx,1:Ny]==2,1,0)*Eq2 \
 + np.where(BC[1:Nx,1:Ny]==3,1,0)*Eq3 \
```

gooing on an on for different Equations...

Thankyou for your help.